# How To Override a base class Method But Auto-Populate The Body Of That Method

Tags: c#, templates, methods, overriding, base-class

I've checked and I'm sure this hasn't already been asked but I have a method in my base class, it's virtual and I override it in my derived class.

```
    public MyBaseClass() 
    { 
       public virtual void MyBaseMethod()
       {
           return a + b; 
       }
    }
```

The question is, is there a way in VS to - rather than just auto-populating the overriden method with

```
return base.MyMethod();
```

To get it to populate that method with what's in the base method or populate it using a template?

For example:

```
public MyDerivedClass()
{
   public override void MyBaseMethod()
   {
      return a + b;  <-- Auto-generated from body of base method
   }
}
```

I know I can do this with Resharper or by setting up a template like the built-in: 'foreach', but is there a way to get this to happen generically without having to create the templates in the first place?
Many thanks.

**UPDATE**

My particular case (actually this is on of two cases) is where I'm overriding my base MVC Controller for my EF Entities.
I've tried using Expressions for filtering but it was far too slow so I'm reverting to - on the occasion that it's needed - a simple if this then add this Where clause, if that then add this Where clause etc. but it's fine because my derived classes know what the Entity type is whereas my base class only knows it from it's Interface.

In my base class:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> onBeforeFinalSelect(IQueryable<T> results)
        {
            return results;
        }
```

In my derived class:

```
public override IQueryable<PostcodePrefixRatingMAP> onBeforeFinalSelect(IQueryable<PostcodePrefixRatingMAP> results)
        {
            return results
                .Include(x => x.PostcodePrefix).AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.Rating.RatingType).AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.Rating).AsNoTracking();
        }
```

**UPDATE 2!**

Ok Imagine this. In my derived class which overrides my base method - and this is really what I'm gunning for - I want it - when overridden to populate the body with a pre-defined template.

For example,
My Base class:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetFilterWhereClause(IQueryable<T> results)
        {
            return results;
        }
```

My derived class:

```
public override IQueryable<PostcodePrefixRatingMAP> GetFilterWhereClause(IQueryable<PostcodePrefixRatingMAP> results)
        {
            foreach (var item in this.DataFiltering.Filters)
            {
                var _intValue = 0;
                switch (item.PropertyName)
                {
                    case "Rating.RatingTypeId":
                        _intValue = item.Value.ToString().ToInt();
                        results = results.Where(x => x.Rating.RatingTypeId == _intValue);
                        break;
                    case "Rating.Description":
                        results = results.Where(x => x.Rating.Description == item.Value.ToString());
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
```

Now this is ONLY required for some entities, a small percentage of my overall entities.

Comment: im curious why you'd want your code to duplicate the base class's code at all?  That's what `base.MyMethod()` is for.  I don't see the benefit

Comment: In some instances I may want to alter it very slightly in the derived class, but it's not something that I can overcome with Generics. I'll update my question with my use case.

Comment: @Jonesopolis I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is "no".  Visual Studio does not provide an automatic way of copying the overridden method body.

To do it relatively quickly via manual means, you could use "Peek Definition" (Alt+F12 for me).  After you create the override and let it fill the body with the `base.XXX` bit, put your cursor on the 'XXX' part and peek the definition.  This will pop up a peek window you can easily copy the base implementation from.

Comment: Thank you. That helps when the base method contains similar code to what I need in the derived method, but I'm still at a loss as to populating with a template.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case you can just add those things to the Base-method call:

Base class:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> onBeforeFinalSelect(IQueryable<T> results)
{
    return results;
}
```

Derived class:

```
public override IQueryable<PostcodePrefixRatingMAP> onBeforeFinalSelect(IQueryable<PostcodePrefixRatingMAP> results)
{
    return base.onBeforeFinalSelect(results)
        .Include(x => x.PostcodePrefix).AsNoTracking()
        .Include(x => x.Rating.RatingType).AsNoTracking()
        .Include(x => x.Rating).AsNoTracking();
}
```

This work because you're returning an `IQueryable`

Comment: This doesn't work because the base class doesn't know all of PostcodePrefixRatingMAP's properties. It only knows it's common properties as per it's interface inheritance in the base class.

Comment: The base class doesn't need to know about them, it can still return the things it knows about. In the derived class you can then tack on any other methods (like in my example). Have you tried it?

Comment: I've just re-read your suggestion, sorry that does of course work. But actually that's not exactly what I'm looking for. My apologies but maybe this wasn't the best method to use as an example because it's body is quite sparse.